# Laravel Mail::send() Send Multiple mails with to and cc addresses

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm new to `Laravel` here.
My aim is to send multiple mails using `Mail::send()` with `to` or `cc`

I have been retrieving my stored emails from `.env` file:

```
toEmails='one@domain.ext','two@domain.ext'
```

Retrieving the emails from a `controller` and sending using the below code:

```
$toEmails = env('toEmails');

$message->to(toEmails); OR $message->cc(toEmails);
```

The following code is continuously resulting with a error:

**Swift_RfcComplianceException in MailboxHeader.php line 345:
Address in mailbox given [[email protected],[email protected]] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.**

I have been trying the below codes which did'nt work for me.
In `.env` file

```
toEmails=array('one@domain.ext','two@domain.ext'),
toEmails=one@domain.ext,two@domain.ext'
```

How can i recover from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set array in the .env file. But the mail method uses array to send emails. So use a comma separated list of emails and then convert them to an array in your controller.

```
// .env file
toEmails=one@domain.ext,two@domain.ext

// controller
$emails = explode(',', env('toEmails'));
```